# Reactjs -- Unreachable code after return statement

Tags: reactjs

I get the following error while executing this piece of code -

Unreachable code after return statement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>React Components</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="react-container"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

        var MyComponent = React.createClass({ 
        render: function(){ return
                <div>MyComponent</div>; } 
                }); 

        React.render(<MyComponent/> ,document.getElementById('react-container'));

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your  `MyComponent` component should be between parenthesis, AFAIK, like: `function(){ return (<div>MyComponent</div>); } })`.

Comment: Also, have the `return` statement and the value you return on the same line. You should also use `ReactDOM.render`.

Comment: Another variation I have experienced is that with function based components and typescript, then the position of the start parenthesis is important, I had 'unreachable' error when the start parenthesis is on itself on a new line, but no errors when following the return statement on the same line. Don't know if this is Babel related?
NO GOOD: 
return (cr/newline return here)
(
   <footer>....
OK: 
return ( (cr/newline here)
      <footer>.....

Answer (score 1):

The problem was probably you are using newer version of babel(versions which comes after 6). Because i faced the same problem like you.Try using a version which is older like as follows,

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem and this solved it. I was using 5.8.24.

Answer (score 0):

JSX cannot be interpreted by browsers so you cannot do things like `return <div>MyComponent</div>` directly in an HTML page that you intend to render on a browser like this. You will need to transpile the JSX into ES5 using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) before gicing it to the browser to interpret.